Can MATLAB's 3D coordinate axes be broken, like "breakxaxis" and "breakyaxis" in 2D graphs?
Break the axes in the 3D diagram.I wonder if this can be done without changing the data.
"breakxaxis" and "breakyaxis" were tried, and it became clear that they only worked with two-dimensional coordinate systems. I want to better show the details I'm interested in,for example
break one of the axes like this:
x x x x // x x x x
95 100 105 110 // 500 505 510 515
clear;
close;
clc;

center_1=[500;500;510];
shape_matrix_1=[1.0 0.5 0.3; 0.3 1 0.2; 0.4 0.5 1.3];
[V_1, D_1] = eig(shape_matrix_1);
numPoints = 20; 
[x_1, y_1, z_1] = ellipsoid(center_1(1), center_1(2), center_1(3), sqrt(D_1(1,1)), sqrt(D_1(2,2)), sqrt(D_1(3,3)), numPoints);    
surf(x_1, y_1, z_1, 'FaceAlpha', 0.3); 

hold on
center_2=[100;105;110];
shape_matrix_2=[1.0 0.5 0.3; 0.3 1 0.4; 0.4 0.5 1.3];
[V_2, D_2] = eig(shape_matrix_1);
numPoints = 20; 
[x_2, y_2, z_2] = ellipsoid(center_2(1), center_2(2), center_2(3), sqrt(D_2(1,1)), sqrt(D_2(2,2)), sqrt(D_2(3,3)), numPoints);    
surf(x_2, y_2, z_2, 'FaceAlpha', 0.3);


Is this different to your previous question?

@ Wolfie  I just wish it could have been done differently. But I've worked it out now, thank you.
